# run time error 1004 on .Refresh BackgroundQuery vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to build a web scraper on pre-defined API. I have used excel's "import from web" for this. This is the code which I am using:

```
    With Sheet7.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Sheet7.Range("connection_string").Value _
    , Destination:=Sheet7.Range("xml_data_start"))
    .Name = Sheet5.Range("search_string")
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

I am getting error on last line (.refresh..). The error is :

> The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
>   1) make sure the specified folder exists
>   2) and 2-3 more lines like this

Strange thing is, this works for some search_string and gives error for some. I have tried most common solution available on google.
I have also tried erasing all established connection in the sheet.
Also, it's working perfectly on all laptops but not on desktops (I know this is weird, but this is the case)

What can be the problem here?